# Tourist Visa (30 days) Dubai valid until date

Tags: visas, uae, tourist-visas

Today I was informed by VFS that my tourist visa for UAE got approved. I'm travelling to UAE on 16th December 2014 and returning on 7th Jan 2015. But when I checked the "valid until" date on the visa it states 30 December 2014.

Does this date mean I should return before December 30th? Should I get it corrected from VFS?

Answer (score 1):

Visas have two dates:

1. The date you should travel by.
2. The time the visa is valid for *once you enter the country*.

Make sure you are checking the correct date. It sounds like you are looking at the travel by date.

There are two kinds of visit visas, the short term (30 days) and the long term (90 days). These terms define how long you can stay in the country from the date of arrival.